# Why is function's root undefined at some point when there is a clear and well-defined solution?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function
$$ f(x,y,\lambda)=\frac{1}{8} x \left[\left(\lambda ^2+6 \lambda -4\right) y-(\lambda -1)^2 x\right]$$
over real domain $x>0$, $y>0$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

If we set $y=x$ then we have $f(x,x,\lambda)=\frac{1}{8} (8 \lambda -5) x^2$, meaning that $\lambda=5/8$ is the unique $\lambda$ that solves $f(x,x,\lambda)=0$ in the function's domain.

However, if I solve $ f(x,y,\lambda)=0$ for $\lambda$ I find $$\lambda=\frac{x+3 y- \sqrt{y (3 x+13 y)}}{x-y},$$
which is undefined at $x=y$ (but has $5/8$ as its $r\rightarrow v$ limit, found via l'Hopital's rule).

Given that $f(x,x,\lambda)=0$ is solved by a clear and well-defined $\lambda$, why is the general solution to $f(x,y,\lambda)=0$ undefined at $x=y$?

Comment: To apply the quadratic formula, check if the equation $f(x,y,\lambda)=0$ is a quadratic equation in $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x = y$, $f$ becomes a simpler function of $\lambda$. Specifically:

$$ f(x,x,\lambda) = x^2\lambda - \frac{5 x^2}8. $$

Therefore $f(x,x,\lambda) = 0$ is not a quadratic equation in $\lambda.$
What happens to the quadratic formula when $a = 0$?

Your "general" solution makes an assumption you did not account for, and is therefore not a general solution. It is a solution for the case $x \neq y$ only.

But you could try the "other" quadratic formula,
$$
x = \frac{2c}{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}.
$$
This is undefined in the "$+$" case when $x=y$ but the "$-$" case works.
I still would not call that a general solution (because of the undefined root in one case), but at least you can use it to relate the two cases $x=y$ and $x\neq y$ to each other.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is the answer I am accepting because I had never seen the alternative quadratic formula and this is most useful for writing down my solution in a way that is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Let's expand your definition of $f(x,y,\lambda)$, collecting like terms in $\lambda$:

$$\begin{align}
f(x,y,\lambda) 
&= \frac{x}{8} \left( (\lambda^2 + 6 \lambda - 4)y - (\lambda - 1)^2 x \right) \\
&= \frac{x}{8} \left( y \lambda^2 + 6y\lambda - 4y - x \lambda^2 + 2x\lambda - x \right) \\
&= \frac{x}{8} \left( (y-x)\lambda^2 + (2x + 6y)\lambda - (x + 4y)\right).
\end{align}$$
Then you presumably applied the quadratic formula with the choice $$a = y-x, \quad b = 2x+6y, \quad c = -(x+4y).$$
But $f$ is not a quadratic polynomial if $a = 0$, or equivalently, $x = y$.  So we have two cases:  if $x \ne y$, then the quadratic formula yields
$$\begin{align}
\lambda &= \frac{-(x+3y) \pm \sqrt{(x+3y)^2 + (y-x)(x+4y)}}{y-x} \\
&= \frac{x+3y \pm \sqrt{y(3x+13y)}}{x-y} \\
&= \frac{x+3y - \sqrt{y(3x+13y)}}{x-y}
\end{align}$$
where we eliminate the root that lies outside of $\lambda \in [0,1]$; and when $x = y$, the linear solution
$$\lambda = \frac{x+4y}{2(x+3y)} = \frac{5x}{8y} = \frac{5}{8}$$
applies.